# Reading input files using python script

Tags: python

I have a number of directories and each directory has an input file in which values stored like this:

```
1.1, 2.2, 2.87, 3.5
41.3, 305, 300, 712
```

I have written a python script to walk through every directory and read the input file and store the numbers in different variables.
For example, for above input file the script should store the 8 numbers in 8 different variables like a = 1.1, b = 2.2, c = 2.87, d = 3.5, e = 41.3, f = 305, g = 300 and h = 712.

For this purpose, i have written the following script.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
import h5py
from pathlib import Path
a = 0; b = 0; c = 0; d = 0; e = 0; f = 0; g = 0; h = 0
dir_to_scan = "/data/abcd"
p = Path(dir_to_scan)
for x in p.iterdir():
    configfile = x.joinpath("rough.txt")
    with open(float(configfile)) as f:
        f.read("{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}\n{e}, {f}, {g}, {h}")
        #print (a[0])
        f.close()
```

But after execution, it shows the following error:

```
TypeError: integer argument expected, got 'str'
```

Comment: This code has major issues with it. For example, why are you attempting to convert a file name to float before opening it?

Comment: In addition, please indicate the line where the error occurs.

Comment: Read is not scanf. Read expects a number of bytes to read, not a format string.

Comment: even if i dont use float before opening, it shows the same error. @MadPhysicist

Comment: the error occurs in the 12th line. @YiFei

Comment: I'm surprised it lets you get that far with the float. What do you imagine the float conversion does? Why did you put it there?

Comment: I am a begineer in python. Help me in getting desired output from the code. @MadPhysicist

Comment: If I help you, it will be help, not a free code handout. Please tell me what your intent was

Comment: My intention is clear from the question that i posted. I want to read the file and store different values in different variables.

Comment: Did you not get an error on the `open(float(...))` line?

Comment: No. I didnt get that error @YiFei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read the whole file with `f.read()`, split it at each line break (`\n`) and at each comma and convert each value to float:

```
with open(configfile) as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n')
    a, b, c, d = [float(v) for v in lines[0].split(', ')]
    e, f, g, h = [float(v) for v in lines[1].split(', ')]
```

You don't need `f.close()` if you use `with`. The file will be closed at the end of `with` block